# EFM32 Gecko Starter Kit USART1 Receive not working (EFM32G890F128)

Tags: c, uart, gecko, geckoboard, geckosdk

I have been trying to setup a uart on the EFM32 Starter kind and I am now able to send characters out of the EFM32 Starter kit board to a computer, but when I try to receive from the computer using the example, my interrupt gets called once, but the data I get is 0x0 and then after the first character I dont receive the interrupt again.

I modified the code from the application note software that can be found on silab's website: USART/UART Asynchronous mode Application Note software

I have added the code to this question as well.  Has anyone else encountered this?  I must be doing something silly.

I checked the RXDATA register in the debugger and it keeps showing 0 even when I press a the "a" character on the keyboard.  Also the interrupt only fires once, with the rxdata being 0, then I never get an interrupt after that.

Thanks in advance.

```
    /******************************************************************************
 * @file main.c
 * @brief USART/UART Asynchronous mode Application Note software example
 * @author Silicon Labs
 * @version 1.03
 ******************************************************************************
 * @section License
 * <b>(C) Copyright 2014 Silicon Labs, http://www.silabs.com</b>
 *******************************************************************************
 *
 * Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
 * including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
 * freely, subject to the following restrictions:
 *
 * 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
 *    claim that you wrote the original software.
 * 2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
 *    misrepresented as being the original software.
 * 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTY/LIMITATION OF REMEDIES: Silicon Labs has no
 * obligation to support this Software. Silicon Labs is providing the
 * Software "AS IS", with no express or implied warranties of any kind,
 * including, but not limited to, any implied warranties of merchantability
 * or fitness for any particular purpose or warranties against infringement
 * of any proprietary rights of a third party.
 *
 * Silicon Labs will not be liable for any consequential, incidental, or
 * special damages, or any other relief, or for any claim by any third party,
 * arising from your use of this Software.
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

#include <stdint.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#include "bsp.h"


/* Function prototypes */
void uartSetup(void);
void cmuSetup(void);
void uartPutData(uint8_t * dataPtr, uint32_t dataLen);
uint32_t uartGetData(uint8_t * dataPtr, uint32_t dataLen);
void    uartPutChar(uint8_t charPtr);
uint8_t uartGetChar(void);


/* Declare some strings */
const char     welcomeString[]  = "EFM32 RS-232 - Please press a key\r\n";
const char     overflowString[] = "\n---RX OVERFLOW---\n";
const uint32_t welLen           = sizeof(welcomeString) - 1;
const uint32_t ofsLen           = sizeof(overflowString) - 1;

/* Define termination character */
#define TERMINATION_CHAR    '.'

/* Declare a circular buffer structure to use for Rx and Tx queues */
#define BUFFERSIZE          256

volatile struct circularBuffer
{
  uint8_t  data[BUFFERSIZE];  /* data buffer */
  uint32_t rdI;               /* read index */
  uint32_t wrI;               /* write index */
  uint32_t pendingBytes;      /* count of how many bytes are not yet handled */
  bool     overflow;          /* buffer overflow indicator */
} rxBuf, txBuf = { {0}, 0, 0, 0, false };


/* Setup UART1 in async mode for RS232*/
static USART_TypeDef           * uart   = USART1;
static USART_InitAsync_TypeDef uartInit = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;




/******************************************************************************
 * @brief  Main function
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  /* Initialize chip - handle erratas */
  CHIP_Init( );

  /* Initialize clocks and oscillators */
  cmuSetup( );

  /* Initialize UART peripheral */
  uartSetup( );

  /* Initialize Development Kit in EBI mode */
 // BSP_Init(BSP_INIT_DEFAULT);

  /* Enable RS-232 transceiver on Development Kit */
  //BSP_PeripheralAccess(BSP_RS232_UART, true);

  /* When DVK is configured, and no more DVK access is needed, the interface can safely be disabled to save current */
  //BSP_Disable();


  /* Write welcome message to UART */
  uartPutData((uint8_t*) welcomeString, welLen);

  /*  Eternal while loop
   *  CPU will sleep during Rx and Tx. When a byte is transmitted, an interrupt
   *  wakes the CPU which copies the next byte in the txBuf queue to the
   *  UART TXDATA register.
   *
   *  When the predefined termiation character is received, the all pending
   *  data in rxBuf is copied to txBuf and echoed back on the UART */
  while (1)
  {
    /* Wait in EM1 while UART transmits */
    EMU_EnterEM1();

    /* Check if RX buffer has overflowed */
    if (rxBuf.overflow)
    {
      rxBuf.overflow = false;
      uartPutData((uint8_t*) overflowString, ofsLen);
    }

    /* Check if termination character is received */
    if (rxBuf.data[(rxBuf.wrI - 1) % BUFFERSIZE] == TERMINATION_CHAR)
    {
      /* Copy received data to UART transmit queue */
      uint8_t tmpBuf[BUFFERSIZE];
      int     len = uartGetData(tmpBuf, 0);
      uartPutData(tmpBuf, len);
    }
  }
}




/******************************************************************************
* @brief  uartSetup function
*
******************************************************************************/
void uartSetup(void)
{
  /* Enable clock for GPIO module (required for pin configuration) */
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  /* Configure GPIO pins */
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 0, gpioModePushPull, 1);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 1, gpioModeInput, 0);


  /* Prepare struct for initializing UART in asynchronous mode*/
  uartInit.enable       = usartDisable;   /* Don't enable UART upon intialization */
  uartInit.refFreq      = 0;              /* Provide information on reference frequency. When set to 0, the reference frequency is */
  uartInit.baudrate     = 115200;         /* Baud rate */
  uartInit.oversampling = usartOVS16;     /* Oversampling. Range is 4x, 6x, 8x or 16x */
  uartInit.databits     = usartDatabits8; /* Number of data bits. Range is 4 to 10 */
  uartInit.parity       = usartNoParity;  /* Parity mode */
  uartInit.stopbits     = usartStopbits1; /* Number of stop bits. Range is 0 to 2 */
 // uartInit.mvdis        = false;          /* Disable majority voting */
//  uartInit.prsRxEnable  = false;          /* Enable USART Rx via Peripheral Reflex System */
//  uartInit.prsRxCh      = usartPrsRxCh0;  /* Select PRS channel if enabled */

  /* Initialize USART with uartInit struct */
  USART_InitAsync(uart, &uartInit);

  /* Prepare UART Rx and Tx interrupts */
  USART_IntClear(uart, _UART_IFC_MASK);
  USART_IntEnable(uart, UART_IEN_RXDATAV);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);

  /* Enable I/O pins at UART1 location #2 */
  uart->ROUTE = UART_ROUTE_RXPEN | UART_ROUTE_TXPEN | UART_ROUTE_LOCATION_LOC0;

  /* Enable UART */
  USART_Enable(uart, usartEnable);
}



/******************************************************************************
 * @brief  uartGetChar function
 *
 *  Note that if there are no pending characters in the receive buffer, this
 *  function will hang until a character is received.
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
uint8_t uartGetChar( )
{
  uint8_t ch;

  /* Check if there is a byte that is ready to be fetched. If no byte is ready, wait for incoming data */
  if (rxBuf.pendingBytes < 1)
  {
    while (rxBuf.pendingBytes < 1) ;
  }

  /* Copy data from buffer */
  ch        = rxBuf.data[rxBuf.rdI];
  rxBuf.rdI = (rxBuf.rdI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;

  /* Decrement pending byte counter */
  rxBuf.pendingBytes--;

  return ch;
}




/******************************************************************************
 * @brief  uartPutChar function
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
void uartPutChar(uint8_t ch)
{
  /* Check if Tx queue has room for new data */
  if ((txBuf.pendingBytes + 1) > BUFFERSIZE)
  {
    /* Wait until there is room in queue */
    while ((txBuf.pendingBytes + 1) > BUFFERSIZE) ;
  }

  /* Copy ch into txBuffer */
  txBuf.data[txBuf.wrI] = ch;
  txBuf.wrI             = (txBuf.wrI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;

  /* Increment pending byte counter */
  txBuf.pendingBytes++;

  /* Enable interrupt on USART TX Buffer*/
  USART_IntEnable(uart, UART_IEN_TXBL);
}




/******************************************************************************
 * @brief  uartPutData function
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
void uartPutData(uint8_t * dataPtr, uint32_t dataLen)
{
  uint32_t i = 0;

  /* Check if buffer is large enough for data */
  if (dataLen > BUFFERSIZE)
  {
    /* Buffer can never fit the requested amount of data */
    return;
  }

  /* Check if buffer has room for new data */
  if ((txBuf.pendingBytes + dataLen) > BUFFERSIZE)
  {
    /* Wait until room */
    while ((txBuf.pendingBytes + dataLen) > BUFFERSIZE) ;
  }

  /* Fill dataPtr[0:dataLen-1] into txBuffer */
  while (i < dataLen)
  {
    txBuf.data[txBuf.wrI] = *(dataPtr + i);
    txBuf.wrI             = (txBuf.wrI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;
    i++;
  }

  /* Increment pending byte counter */
  txBuf.pendingBytes += dataLen;

  /* Enable interrupt on USART TX Buffer*/
  USART_IntEnable(uart, UART_IEN_TXBL);
}

/******************************************************************************
 * @brief  uartGetData function
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
uint32_t uartGetData(uint8_t * dataPtr, uint32_t dataLen)
{
  uint32_t i = 0;

  /* Wait until the requested number of bytes are available */
  if (rxBuf.pendingBytes < dataLen)
  {
    while (rxBuf.pendingBytes < dataLen) ;
  }

  if (dataLen == 0)
  {
    dataLen = rxBuf.pendingBytes;
  }

  /* Copy data from Rx buffer to dataPtr */
  while (i < dataLen)
  {
    *(dataPtr + i) = rxBuf.data[rxBuf.rdI];
    rxBuf.rdI      = (rxBuf.rdI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;
    i++;
  }

  /* Decrement pending byte counter */
  rxBuf.pendingBytes -= dataLen;

  return i;
}

/***************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Set up Clock Management Unit
 ******************************************************************************/
void cmuSetup(void)
{
  /* Start HFXO and wait until it is stable */
  /* CMU_OscillatorEnable( cmuOsc_HFXO, true, true); */

  /* Select HFXO as clock source for HFCLK */
  /* CMU_ClockSelectSet(cmuClock_HF, cmuSelect_HFXO ); */

  /* Disable HFRCO */
  /* CMU_OscillatorEnable( cmuOsc_HFRCO, false, false ); */

  /* Enable clock for HF peripherals */
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFPER, true);

  /* Enable clock for USART module */
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART1, true);
}


/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief UART1 RX IRQ Handler
 *
 * Set up the interrupt prior to use
 *
 * Note that this function handles overflows in a very simple way.
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART1_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* Check for RX data valid interrupt */
  if (uart->IF & UART_IF_RXDATAV)
  {
    /* Copy data into RX Buffer */
    uint8_t rxData = USART_Rx(uart);
    rxBuf.data[rxBuf.wrI] = rxData;
    rxBuf.wrI             = (rxBuf.wrI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;
    rxBuf.pendingBytes++;

    /* Flag Rx overflow */
    if (rxBuf.pendingBytes > BUFFERSIZE)
    {
      rxBuf.overflow = true;
    }
  }
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief UART1 TX IRQ Handler
 *
 * Set up the interrupt prior to use
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART1_TX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* Check TX buffer level status */
  if (uart->IF & UART_IF_TXBL)
  {
    if (txBuf.pendingBytes > 0)
    {
      /* Transmit pending character */
      USART_Tx(uart, txBuf.data[txBuf.rdI]);
      txBuf.rdI = (txBuf.rdI + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;
      txBuf.pendingBytes--;
    }

    /* Disable Tx interrupt if no more bytes in queue */
    if (txBuf.pendingBytes == 0)
    {
      USART_IntDisable(uart, UART_IEN_TXBL);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well there may be a tx issue with 'USART_IntEnable(uart, UART_IEN_TXBL);'  I'm not that familiar with STM2 UARTs but, with other devices, it's common for the tx interrupt to be raised only when the hardware tx buffer becomes empty.  If that buffer is already empty, and you enable the interrupt, no interrupt will occur because the buffer has not become empty while interrupts are enabled.  It is often necessary to 'prime' the tx interrupt by 'manually' sending the first character.

Comment: I have removed that, but ran into the same issue.  Does anyone know what the input levels of the Serial receive pin should be.  Is it TTL levels (0 to 5V), my board that I have produces 1.8V levels.  Could that be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Hi there, did you have any luck solving this? I'm after running into the same issue.